# Segment Fault Issue For NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, server, segmentation-fault, cloud

I'm getting segment fault issue for Nodejs with higher version but with v10 I am not getting that error, what can be issue here .

I am pasting few logs here from server

**Segment Handler Logs**

```
PID 3832995 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x2
/var/www/Nodedemo/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node(+0x3785)[0x7f80d0424785]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x14420)[0x7f80d00c0420]
/lib/libgcwrap.so(+0x5766)[0x7f80d042d766]
/lib/libgcwrap.so(accept4+0x80)[0x7f80d0430f52]
node[0x154d5c4]
node[0x15593bb]
node[0x155ee34]
node(uv_run+0x138)[0x154d058]
node(_ZN4node13SpinEventLoopEPNS_11EnvironmentE+0x145)[0xa43975]
node(_ZN4node16NodeMainInstance3RunEv+0x186)[0xb4b146]
node(_ZN4node5StartEiPPc+0x9c)[0xaccbcc]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x7f80cfedc083]
node[0xa408ec]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Core Dump with gdb logs**

```
[New LWP 3832995]
[New LWP 3832996]
[New LWP 3832998]
[New LWP 3832997]
[New LWP 3832999]
[New LWP 3833000]
[New LWP 3833001]

warning: Could not load shared library symbols for /lib/libgcwrap.so.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `node index.js'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f80d042d766 in ?? ()
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f80cfeb1d40 (LWP 3832995))]
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f80d042d766 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Please help me in this

Tried removing node npm and related packages as well but not resolved

Comment: a week ago I encountered this issue too after power outage, the fix nowhere to be found, my solution was clean install ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Check if your server is not infected with a malware, the only reference I found on the internet about libgcwrap is :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1641230

It led me to find a perfcc call in /etc/cron.daily/perfclean
perfcc is apparently a crypto miner malware. I was noticing huge slowdowns on my server right before I had issues with it.

I can't advise you on how to remove it right now because I just found out about it.